# Не могу изменить colorPrimaryDark

Tags: android, android-xml

У меня какая-то ошибка в colorPrimaryDark. В главной странице она работает, но во второй уже не работает. Прошу помочь

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

colors.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#27253B</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#26233C</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
    <color name="actionButton">#343A70</color>
    <color name="numberButton">#6F3453</color>

</resources>
```

styles.xml

```
  <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/CustomActivityAnimation</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <style name="CustomActivityAnimation" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity">

        <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_in_right</item>
        <item name="android:activityOpenExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_left</item>
        <item name="android:activityCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_in_left</item>
        <item name="android:activityCloseExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_right</item>
    </style>


    <style name="ActionButtonStyle">
        <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/actionButton</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">25dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:layout_margin">0.5dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="NumberButtonStyle">
        <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/numberButton</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">25dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:layout_margin">0.5dp</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.fleeploed.mathematicsapp">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="Математика"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Calculator"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_calculator"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AlgGeom10"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_alg_geom10"
        android:parentActivityName=".VectorMathAndGeom"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TheorieVer"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_theorie_ver"
        android:parentActivityName=".FormulasActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Logarifms"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_logarifms"
        android:parentActivityName=".FormulasActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TablicaProizvodnych"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_tablica_proizvodnych"
        android:parentActivityName=".FormulasActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AlgGeom9"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_alg_geom9"
        android:parentActivityName=".VectorMathAndGeom"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AlgGeom8"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_alg_geom8"
        android:parentActivityName=".VectorMathAndGeom"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AlgGeom7"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_alg_geom7"
        android:parentActivityName=".VectorMathAndGeom"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AlgGeom6"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_alg_geom6"
        android:parentActivityName=".VectorMathAndGeom"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AlgGeom5"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_alg_geom5"
        android:parentActivityName=".VectorMathAndGeom"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AlgGeom4"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_alg_geom4"
        android:parentActivityName=".VectorMathAndGeom"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AlgGeom3"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_alg_geom3"
        android:parentActivityName=".VectorMathAndGeom"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AlgGeom2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_alg_geom2"
        android:parentActivityName=".VectorMathAndGeom"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Alggeom1"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_vektornaya"
        android:parentActivityName=".VectorMathAndGeom"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Trigonomeria"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_trigonomeria"
        android:parentActivityName=".FormulasActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Progresii"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_progresii"
        android:parentActivityName=".FormulasActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".FormulSokr"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_formul_sokr"
        android:parentActivityName=".FormulasActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Priznakidelimosti"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_priznakidelimosti"
        android:parentActivityName=".FormulasActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ModulFomulas"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_modul_fomulas"
        android:parentActivityName=".FormulasActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".FormulasActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_formulas"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".VectorMathAndGeom"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_vector_math_and_geom"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-3860319943737586~8102242104" />
</application>
```

Comment: В манифесте или в layout есть строка на какой стиль ссылается ваша "вторая страница"?

Comment: покажите код файла манифеста..